# When debugging with IntelliJ IDEA, what do the different variable colors mean?

Tags: java, debugging, variables, intellij-idea

So when debugging with IntelliJ IDEA, the Variable Window often looks like this:

[image]

(the white box is added by me afterwards)

Now i have some variables colored red, others colored blue.

Whats the meaning of the color, what is difference between these colors?
I have also noticed red variables with blue fields and the other way around.

I didnt find anything on the web about this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Red is the standard color for variables.

Blue indicates that a variable has changed while you're stepping through the code. If you continue to the next iteration of your loop (assuming offlineNotifications is a Collection), you will see those are the variables manipulated in the current execution of code.

Comment: Does this mean that this variable value is up-to-date or not?